# Spring with hibernate cache native query

Tags: spring, ehcache

I'm using Spring 3.2 with Hibernate 4. In my DAO implementation I want to cache the results of native SQL query. The method to get results of this query looks like this:

```
public List<Object[]> getBestSellers(String category)
{
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

    Query query = session.createSQLQuery( "SELECT i_id, i_title, a_fname, a_lname , SUM(ol_qty) AS val " +
            "FROM " +
            "orders, order_line, item, author " +
            "WHERE " +
            "order_line.ol_o_id = orders.o_id AND item.i_id = order_line.ol_i_id " +
            "AND item.i_subject = :category AND item.i_a_id = author.a_id GROUP BY i_id " +
            "ORDER BY orders.o_date, val DESC" );

    query.setParameter( "category", category );
    query.setMaxResults( 50 );
    query.setCacheable( true );

    List<Object[]> res = query.list();

    return res;
}
```

It seems like that doesn't work and I don't know why.

I have configured the Hibernate in applicationContext.xml like this:

```
<props>
    <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">50</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.hibernate.dialect}</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">4</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</prop>    
    <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_configuration_file_resource_path">classpath:ehcache.xml</prop> 
    <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</prop>
</props>
```

and my ehcache.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ehcache.org/ehcache.xsd">    
    <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir/Cloudscale-cache"/>
    <defaultCache 
        eternal="false" 
        maxElementsInMemory="1000"
        overflowToDisk="false" 
        diskPersistent="false" 
        timeToIdleSeconds="0"
        timeToLiveSeconds="600" 
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"
    />
    <cache 
        name="org.hibernate.cache.spi.UpdateTimestampsCache"
        maxElementsInMemory="50"
        eternal="false"
        timeToIdleSeconds="0"
        timeToLiveSeconds="86400"
        overflowToDisk="true"/>
    <cache 
        name="org.hibernate.cache.internal.StandardQueryCache"
        maxElementsInMemory="50"
        eternal="false"
        timeToIdleSeconds="0"
        timeToLiveSeconds="86400"
        overflowToDisk="true"/> 
</ehcache>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to cache native sql queries then you have to use `addScalar()`
by using `addScalar()` ;hibernate will try to converted result of sql query into return objects for individual named columns, rather than entities.

Modify your query as below

```
 Query query = session.createSQLQuery( "SELECT i_id as a, i_title as b, a_fname as c, a_lname as d, SUM(ol_qty) AS val " +
            "FROM " +
            "orders, order_line, item, author " +
            "WHERE " +
            "order_line.ol_o_id = orders.o_id AND item.i_id = order_line.ol_i_id " +
            "AND item.i_subject = :category AND item.i_a_id = author.a_id GROUP BY i_id " +
            "ORDER BY orders.o_date, val DESC" ).addScalar("a").addScalar("b").addScalar("c").addScalar("d").addScalar("val");
```

Comment: I think this doesn't help, because in logs there isn't any record that would say anything about getting results from cache. Also page load for this query isn't any faster.

Comment: are you sure query didn't get loaded from cache during second time

Comment: also can you try explict setCacheable(true) on query object

Comment: Well, I used Spring cache instead of query caching then.